# Does anyone know how to format the Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anyone know how to format the Jquery datepicker? I want it to display it like dd/mm/yyyy and that is the only way I want to display it, but at the moment it is displaying it like mm/dd/yyyy.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
   $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({format("dd/mm/yyyy")});
    });
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The documentation is a great thing! http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#options

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look at the documetation for other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key you want is [`dateFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
});
```